# PHP: Can't use inheritance. It won't find the class

Tags: php, inheritance, classnotfound

I reached the cap about inheritance but I can't use them, even when I try to use the examples from the book I'm learning. Even though all the files are on the same folder, the error is:

> "Fatal error: Class 'mother' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\Learning\classes\son.php on line 2"

Let me show a exemple I created to explain.

FILE: **mother.php**:

```
    <?php
    class mother
    {
       public $word= "Hello!!!";

       function printWord()
       {
         echo $word;   
       }
     }
     ?>
```

FILE: **son.php**:

```
<?php 
  class son extends mother
   {
     function printWord()
     {
      parent::printWord();
     }
   }  
?>
```

FILE: **test.php**:

```
<?php
include 'son.php';
$test = new son();
$test->printWord();
?>
```

Results in:

> ERROR: Fatal error: Class 'mother' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\Learning\classes\son.php on line 2

Why is this happening? Why it won't find the class if it is on the same folder ?!

Comment: Instead of trying to require each file by yourself, I suggest to read up on [PHP and autoloading](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the `mother.php` too. Otherwise it can't find the class as the error states.

*Naive example:*

test.php

```
<?php
include 'mother.php'
include 'son.php';
$test = new son();
$test->printWord();
?>
```

*But there is even a better way*

son.php

```
<?php 
  require_once 'mother.php'
  class son extends mother
   {
     function printWord()
     {
      parent::printWord();
     }
   }  
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering . Error still happens using both of yours solutions. Is that any configuration on my local server that can be wrong? Because even when I try the examples from my book this error pops up.

Comment: @FernandoAnaelCabral Alright. Could you provide more info and the current code?